# How to get the current state of the screen: HomeScreen, OverviewScreen ... in AccessibilityService?

Tags: android

I have `AccessibilityService`

```
 override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        if (event != null) {
            when (event.eventType) {
                AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED -> {
```

How will I determine with certainly, regardless of the launcher, whether or not the current window is the Home Screen? I've tried this

```
if (event.packageName.endsWith("launcher")) { ....
```

but it won't always work. Meaning, on the same phone it'll sometimes work, other times not. On top on this, there may be other launchers as well: MIUI, ColourOS, standard Android one, etc... therefore, `.endsWith("launcher")` becomes even less reliable.

How will I do this?

Also, is there any way to determine whether the current screen is the one when the Overview Button has been pressed?